# EF 6 : Nested Complex type in another complex type

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Suppose that I have a Entity called "car".

I use a complex type to define the "Engine" part.

```
[TableName("T_CAR")]
public sealed class Car:IEngine
{
  ...
  public EngineType EngineType{get;set;}

}

[ComplexType]
public sealed class Engine:IEngine
{

  public Engin( )
  {
    this.EnginType = new EngineType( );
  }

  public EngineType EngineType{get;set;}

  // other properties ...

}

[ComplexType]
public sealed class EngineType:IEngineType
{
  ...     
}
```

When I run this code, I have a error message from EF 6 :

System.InvalidOperationException: The type 'Engine' has already been configured as an entity type. It cannot be reconfigured as a complex type.

And if I remove the definition of EngineType, it works ...

Is there a way to add a nested complex type in another complex type ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit**: This has changed, EF6 now supports nested complex types, just remember to set each one as a complex type.

```
public class EngineConfiguration : ComplexTypeConfiguration<Engine>
{
}
public class EngineTypeConfiguration : ComplexTypeConfiguration<EngineType>
{
}
```

Then in your context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EngineConfiguration());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EngineTypeConfiguration());
}
```

---

Original answer: No, ComplexTypes may only contain primitive types. I first read this in Julie Lermans book
[Programming entity framework code first](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022220.do),
I don't believe this restriction has been lifted in EF6.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. In my application I got it to work with nested types. But looking at your code I can't spot the error. I used fluent configuration though instead of data attributes.

```
protected sealed override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  modelBuilder.ComplexType<SampleComplexType>();
}
```

Comment: I didn't expect this to work with nested complex types but I can confirm it worked for me as well.