# Scaffolding Not Detecting Complext Type Property in an Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I am using MVC Scaffolding + EF6 in a Web applicatioon project in VS 2013.

Domain classes (Entites) and the context (`DbContext`) are in two separate projects referenced by the Web project.

I have a Patient class which has a complex property like follows.

```
public class Patient
{
    public int PatientId { get; set; }

    // Some properties

    // Complex property
    public MyComplexType Complex { get; set; }
}

public class MyComplexType
{
    public SomeType Property1 { get; set; }
    public SomeOtherType Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

**Problem:**

MVC scaffolding engine does not detect the complex property in `Patient` class and generated views don't contain fields to show or edit that property. I tried decorating `MyComplexType` class with `ComplexType` attribute but it didn't work.

What can be done?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20332503/1211622) and Julie Lerman's book *Programming Entity Framework: Code First*, complex types can only contain primitive properties.

**Conventional Complex Type Rules**

1. Complex types have no key property.
2. Complex types can only contain primitive properties.
3. When used as a property in another class, the property must represent a single
   instance. It cannot be a collection type.

In my case I am using an unconventional complex type so I should have decorated `MyComplexType` class with `ComplexType` attribute too.

```
public class Patient
{
    public int PatientId { get; set; }

    // Some properties

    // Complex property
    public MyComplexType Complex { get; set; }
}

[ComplexType]
public class MyComplexType
{
    public SomeType Property1 { get; set; }
    public SomeOtherType Property2 { get; set; }
}


public class SomeType
{
    // primitive  properties here
}

public class SomeOtherType 
{
    // primitive  properties here
}
```

HTH